# Provide a way to easily link to the chat sandbox in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat

Feature request: a fun and easy way to link to the [Sandbox room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1/sandbox).

Currently (4:01 AM Tuesday, July 23, 2013 UTC), the chat [formatting FAQ](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq#formatting) mentions the Sandbox room at the bottom.

I wish I could just do something like `[sandbox]` or `[chat-sandbox]` just like typing `[so]` or `[meta]`. Might be also good to provide a link to the room on the pop-up that shows whenever I click on the help link.

@Rapptz also suggested `[chat.sandbox]` or `[chat:sandbox]`. :-)